# How can I make an element observable, which has been ajax imported?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Using the Webmail example, let's say I like to make the Date in each row ko.observable
http://learn.knockoutjs.com/WebmailExampleStandalone.html

*In the real world, rather then Date there would be a check box or something!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map your data into knockout and use ko applybindings.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html

Answer (score 1):

Either map it manual or you can use the mapping pluggin

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html